# CData not rendered in browser

Tags: javascript, dom, rss, cdata

```js
function feed_fetch(){
    const div = document.getElementById('feed');
    div.innerHTML = "";
    const url = "https://some-rss-url";
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {
            const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
            items.forEach(item => {
                const html = `
                    <article>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="${item.querySelector("link").innerHTML}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                        ${item.querySelector("title").innerHTML}
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    </article>
                `;
                div.innerHTML += html;
            })
        });
}
```

The results of the fetch includes some CData such as `<![CDATA[ "some text" ]]>`.

In the resulting HTML generated, the parts inside CDATA do not appear. If I manually remove the CDATA enveloppe it works.

I could just find/replace the enveloppe. However is there a correct way of handling this?

Comment: How are you checking for CDATA?

Comment: what do you mean? I can see that the content of the `title` or `description` tags are wrapped in a CDATA tag.